# How to mock a nested function with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I've tried a couple of approaches but I'm not sure if it's possible to mock a nested function in Jest. I read the official docs where they use axios, but I'm trying to mock a function that is imported, not a module.

for example, I have some function A, and within A I call B. I want to mock B so that it returns true once and then false once.

B is a function I imported that I wrote in another file, and I'm testing A.

so far I have tried to import function B into my test file and create a mock of it, but I don't think it's working how I thought it would

for example I have tried this

```
import { b } from "../util"
jest.mock("b", () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true));
```

and then my tested file would be

```
function a() => {
  while b() {
    do something;
  }
}
```

should I rewrite my test or function I'm testing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of results you are getting, but for mocking b you could do:

```
jest.mock("../util", () => ({
  b:jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true).mockReturnValueOnce(false),
}));
```